# embed angular2 in php

Tags: php, angular

is it possible to call an Angular2 page from withing a PHP server function

I want to work with Angular2 but our legacy app is written in PHP.

[image]

Comment: Assuming your Angular 2 code is meant to run in a browser you're not going to have a good time here. PHP doesn't know how to execute JavaScript code. Though it may be possible to [run it server-side](https://universal.angular.io/)…

Comment: maybe this will help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552842/what-is-server-side-rendering-using-angular2